# ValueEventlistener calling intent repeating the Intent call on other Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i have called an Activity from an Intent, the putExtra values are derived from the a ValueEventListener/SingleValueEventlistner of Firebase in android. But when the Intent is called the Activty which is to be opened keeps getting called over and over again. Here is the code of the listener and intent

```
public void onSignInInitailize(String name)
{
    displayName = name;
    name = name.replace(" ","");
    Email =  "FY1/" + name;
    query = databaseReference.getRef();
    valueEventlistner = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            sfy1 = (String) dataSnapshot.child(Email).getValue();
            intent = new Intent(getApplication(),StudentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", displayName);
            intent.putExtra("class",sfy1);
            startActivity(intent);
            if(sfy1.equals("true"))
            {
                query.removeEventListener(this);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
            }
    };
    query.addValueEventListener(valueEventlistner);
    System.out.println(sfy1);
}
```

the method is called when Firebase Auth checks for User!=null. I have tried detaching the listener onPause but of no use.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How often is onSignInInitailize called?
Are you sure you are not registering a lot of new ValueEventListeners?

Comment: This is the only valueEventListener I am attaching, onSignInInitialized also gets initialized once.